# Using functions and objects in JSONP response, is it valid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsonp

I'm playing around with functions and JSONP (jsfiddle as proof: https://jsfiddle.net/evzy6qvd/)

This is my JSONP result:

```
jsonCallback({
    response: {
        aVal: "val",
        aFunction: function() {
            console.log("I'm a function set in the JSONP result");
            alert("I'm a function set in the JSONP result");
        }
    }
})
```

And this is called by jQuery like this:

```
(function($) {
var url = 'https://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=M3vFvkbG';

$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: url,
    async: false,
    jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(json) {
       json.response.aFunction(); // <== note this one
    },
    error: function(e) {
       console.log(e.message);
    }
});

})(jQuery);
```

This actually works, but is it valid? It could be useful in applications I guess, are there any implementation examples of this?

Comment: If by "valid", you mean it's correct JSONP, then no. But since JSONP is just a `script` request, it will work as you can see. If you're going to do that, I'd just request a script instead.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Wouldn't this solve a possible crossdomain issue with the `script` tag?

Comment: Yes, if the server sends JSONP, it solves that issue. Of course it isn't secure since any code sent is executed, but if you trust the source, then it helps.